# How could I return to ruby's config default settings?

Tags: ruby, config

I add this config in my terminal, but now I wan´t to remove it, how could I?

code in terminal: bundle config set without 'production'

Regards

Comment: Hint: `bundle config --help`.

Comment: I am not sure how to know the <name>, because it says 'Executing `bundle config unset <name>` will delete the configuration in both local and global sources.'  
And when I print the list it says 'with
Set for the current user (C:/Users/Eduardo/.bundle/config): [:production]
'

Comment: It's telling you where the config is. Check out that file and see what's up.

Comment: Thanks maybe thats not the best, but I delet it and it works!!!

Comment: Worth adding a self-answer with your exact process. Might help someone in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it
 `bundle config list` and here says where the congis are, so go to that folder and delete the ones you want or the complete folder